# Is there a way to find the area of "Beauchamp's mouth" on the interval from $0$ to $2\pi$?

Tags: calculus

This is an extra credit problem on a homework assignment.  I'm guessing it might not be doable using traditional methods but I'm not sure.  I am asked to compute the area between the following two curves (the so-called "mouth of Beauchamp".  it looks like this:

$y = cos(sin(x))$

$y = sin(cos(x))$

On the interval $0 \leq x  \leq 2\pi$

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica says that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(\sin x)\>dx=2\pi\>J_0(1)\doteq4.80788\ ,$$
where $J_0(x)$ is the Bessel function of order zero. On the other hand
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\cos x)\>dx=0\ ,$$
by symmetry.

The first integral can be developed into a fast convergent series as follows:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(\sin x)\>dx=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{(-1)^k\sin^{2k}x\over(2k)!}\>dx\ .$$
The integrals $Q_k:=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2k}x\>dx$ satisfy the following recursion, obtained via partial integration:
$$Q_0={\pi/2},\qquad Q_k={2k-1\over 2k}Q_{k-1}\qquad(k\geq1)\ .$$
Now put it all together, and you will obtain the series for $2\pi\, J_0(1)$.